# Como passar um parâmetro num verbo GET quando estou usando xdebug - NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, xdebug

Tenho uma página `mySite.com/api/v1/listUsers.json.php` que vai retornar uma lista de usuários para ser consumida numa app. Porém gostaria de aproveitar essa mesma página e criar a seguinte condição para o pessoal do desenvolvimento: se uma variável for enviada E o valor dessa variável for igual a "arr" a resposta será uma array. Somente para os desenvolvedores visualizarem rapidamente os valores na tabela de usuários.

`Exemplo: mySite.com/api/v1/listUsers.json.php?type=arr`.

POr algum motivo não está dando certo. Eu estou tentando fazer o debug com o xdebug mas não sei como passar o parâmetro type=arr para ser debugado.

Estou usando xdebug em Netbeans.

Como faço isso?

Answer (score 0):

Poderia colocar um pedaço do código para avaliarmos.
Mas basicamente seria algo do tipo:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['type']) && 'arr' === $_GET['type']) {
    return $jsonInArrayFormat; // Retorna o json no formato de array
}

return $jsonDefault; // Retorna o json comum
```